# Net::SMTP: Net::Cmd::_is_closed(): unexpected EOF on command channel [perl]

Tags: windows, perl, email

im trying to send email via perl trough yahoo smtp server , and my code run on linux with no error but when i run this code on windows server 2008 r2 perl sys :

> Net::SMTP>>> Net::SMTP(3.07)
>
> Net::SMTP>>>   Net::Cmd(3.07)
>
> Net::SMTP>>>     Exporter(5.72)
>
> Net::SMTP>>>   IO::Socket::IP(0.37)
>
> Net::SMTP>>>     IO::Socket(1.38)
>
> Net::SMTP>>>       IO::Handle(1.35)
>
> Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2b41c30)<<< 220 smtp.mail.yahoo.com ESMTP ready
>
> Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2b41c30)>>> EHLO smtp.mail.yahoo.com
>
> Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2b41c30)<<< 250-smtp.mail.yahoo.com
>
> Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2b41c30)<<< 250-PIPELINING
>
> Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2b41c30)<<< 250-SIZE 41697280
>
> Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2b41c30)<<< 250-8 BITMIME
>
> Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2b41c30)<<< 250 STARTTLS
>
> Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2b41c30)>>> STARTTLS
>
> Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2b41c30)<<< 220 2.0.0 Start TLS
>
> Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2b41c30)>>> RCPT TO:
>
> Net::SMTP: Net::Cmd::getline(): unexpected EOF on command channel: Bad
>   file descriptor at test.pl line 16.
>
> Net::SMTP: Net::Cmd::_is_closed(): unexpected EOF on command channel:
>   Bad file descriptor at test.pl line 17.

my code is:

```
use Net::SMTP 3.03;

my $mailer = Net::SMTP->new(
    'smtp.mail.yahoo.com',
    Hello   =>      'smtp.mail.yahoo.com',
    Port    =>      587,
    Debug => 1,
);

$mailer->starttls();
$mailer->auth('test','123');
    #!$mailer->mail('test@yahoo.com');
    $mailer->to('test@yahoo.com');
    $mailer->data();
    $mailer->datasend('From: test@yahoo.com \r\n');
    $mailer->datasend('To: test@yahoo.com \r\n');
    $mailer->datasend('Subject: testing \r\n');
    $mailer->datasend('Content-type: text/html \r\n\n');
    $mailer->datasend('\n');
    $mailer->datasend('test test test\r\n');
    $mailer->dataend();
$mailer->quit;
```

what is the problem ?

result with "perl -MIO::Socket::SSL=debug4 test.pl"

> Net::SMTP>>> Net::SMTP(3.07)
>
> Net::SMTP>>>   Net::Cmd(3.07)
>
> Net::SMTP>>>     Exporter(5.72)
>
> Net::SMTP>>>   IO::Socket::IP(0.37)
>
> Net::SMTP>>>     IO::Socket(1.38)
>
> Net::SMTP>>>       IO::Handle(1.35)
>
> Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2dade80)<<< 220 smtp.mail.yahoo.com ESMTP ready
>
> Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2dade80)>>> EHLO smtp.mail.yahoo.com
>
> Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2dade80)<<< 250-smtp.mail.yahoo.com
>
> Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2dade80)<<< 250-PIPELINING
>
> Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2dade80)<<< 250-SIZE 41697280
>
> Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2dade80)<<< 250-8 BITMIME
>
> Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2dade80)<<< 250 STARTTLS
>
> Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2dade80)>>> STARTTLS
>
> Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2dade80)<<< 220 2.0.0 Start TLS
>
> DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:568: global error: SSL Version SSLv2 not
>   supported
>
> Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x2dade80)>>> MAIL FROM:
>
> Net::SMTP: Net::Cmd::getline(): unexpected EOF on command channel: Bad
>   file descriptor at test.pl line 15.
>
> Net::SMTP: Net::Cmd::_is_closed(): unexpected EOF on command channel:
>   Bad file descriptor at test.pl line 16.
>
> Net::SMTP: Net::Cmd::_is_closed(): unexpected EOF on command channel:
>   Bad file descriptor at test.pl line 16.
>
> Net::SMTP: Net::Cmd::_is_closed(): unexpected EOF on command channel:
>   Bad file descriptor at test.pl line 17.
>
> Net::SMTP: Net::Cmd::_is_closed(): unexpected EOF on command channel:
>   Bad file descriptor at test.pl line 17.
>
> Net::SMTP: Net::Cmd::_is_closed(): unexpected EOF on command channel:
>   Bad file descriptor at test.pl line 18.
>
> Net::SMTP: Net::Cmd::_is_closed(): unexpected EOF on command channel:
>   Bad file descriptor at test.pl line 19.
>
> Net::SMTP: Net::Cmd::_is_closed(): unexpected EOF on command channel:
>   Bad file descriptor at test.pl line 20.
>
> Net::SMTP: Net::Cmd::_is_closed(): unexpected EOF on command channel:
>   Bad file descriptor at test.pl line 21.
>
> Net::SMTP: Net::Cmd::_is_closed(): unexpected EOF on command channel:
>   Bad file descriptor at test.pl line 22.
>
> Net::SMTP: Net::Cmd::_is_closed(): unexpected EOF on command channel:
>   Bad file dscriptor at test.pl line 23.
>
> Net::SMTP: Net::Cmd::_is_closed(): unexpected EOF on command channel:
>   Bad file descriptor at test.pl line 24.
>
> Net::SMTP: Net::Cmd::_is_closed(): unexpected EOF on command channel:
>   Bad file descriptor at test.pl line 25.
>
> Net::SMTP: Net::Cmd::_is_closed(): unexpected EOF on command channel:
>   Bad file d

Comment: The login is missing in the debug output.  This will happen if Authen::SASL is not or not properly installed.

Comment: That's all very strange. Usually there is another EHLO after the STARTTLS but not in your debug output. But it is there if I run your code myself with the same version of Net::SMTP. Also, your RCPT TO gets sent before the STARTTLS is done. Can you please run your code with `perl -MIO::Socket::SSL=debug4 test.pl`  and the debug output to the question (not in a comment)

Comment: And please add error checking. starttls will return false if the SSL handshake failed which is probably the case for you. Try to install Mozilla::CA to get up-to-date root certificates usable from Perl.

Comment: ok i added result to my question.

Comment: "...SSL Version SSLv2 not supported" - I have the feeling that your version of IO::Socket::SSL is not the original one but probably one which received (wrong) patches to work around problems with the broken Net::SMTP::TLS. Please make sure that you have installed an unchanged and current version of IO::Socket::SSL.

Comment: thanks solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

"...SSL Version SSLv2 not supported" - I have the feeling that your version of IO::Socket::SSL is not the original one but probably one which received (wrong) patches to work around problems with the broken Net::SMTP::TLS. Please make sure that you have installed an unchanged and current version of IO::Socket::SSL. – Steffen Ullrich