# Net::SMTP::SSL (via gmail and amazon smtp) - 'Connection Closed' when sending email with attachment

Tags: perl, email, gmail, amazon-ses

I have a perl export script which generates a .csv file and then emails it to the user. I've gone down this route because we do not want the user to have to wait on a specific page for the export to finish, instead allowing it to be exported in the background.

However, when the csv is attached and the email sent I get the following error:

`[Net::SMTP::SSL] Connection closed`

I can't put a lot of the code here, but I can at least show you what part of the code is reporting this error. I am wondering if anyone here knows why this might be happening, or an easy way to debug it.

Here's the code block for sending the email (with comment for where error is reported):

```
my $mailer = new Net::SMTP::SSL($smtp, Port => $port) or die "Cannot create a SSL mailer instance!\n";
$mailer->auth($user, $pass) or die ("Can't authenticate");

$mailer->mail($email) or die $mailer->message;
$mailer->to(split(',', $to)) or die $mailer->message;
$mailer->data() or die $mailer->message;
$mailer->datasend($msg->as_string) or die $mailer->message; # Connection closed
$mailer->dataend() or die $mailer->message;
$mailer->quit() or die $mailer->message;
```

Please let me know if there's any other information needed. I will try and provide what I can. This is difficult to resolve because the error is so ambiguous.

**NOTE:** The emails successfully send when removing the offending attachment, and sometimes send depending on the csv content.

Comment: Please  add all the details to make the issue reproducible. If the problem happens only with a specific mail content you need to add this content to the question. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich While I wish I could add the content of the csv, the content in question is sensitive data that I cannot provide. I understand that only complicates the matter but I am sort of grasping at straws, seeing if anyone has run into issues with certain content resulting in rejected / closed smtp connections with gmail.

Comment: You do not need to add the original (sensitive) content which causes the problem but just some (non-sensitive) content which causes the problem is enough. I suspect that you will not get help with your admittingly strange problem is there is no way to reproduce it. Also make sure that you are using the latest versions of Net::SMTP (which is used by Net::SMTP::SSL) in case there were known but fixed bugs.

Comment: I do not know what in the entire csv is causing it. In order to do that I'd need to go row by row, column by column to figure out where the issue is happening (30+ columns, and over a hundred rows). This would also not be a catch all, because I would then need to test this on multiple exports since any of the data could possibly cause a similar issue.

Comment: As suggested in the answer: It's more likely the size of the mail than the content of the CSV. Did you try sending something useless with the same size? Sensitive content should be PGP-encrypted anyway, sending it via Amazon and probably also Google is like uploading it to NSA servers yourself.

Comment: The file is not too large. It is 246KB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an unexpected EOF report by the debugger. This is a duplicate [Net::SMTP: Net::Cmd::_is_closed(): unexpected EOF on command channel [perl]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34286837/netsmtp-netcmd-is-closed-unexpected-eof-on-command-channel-perl)

New Error: `Net::SMTP::SSL: Net::Cmd::datasend(): unexpected EOF on command channel`

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by a bug in Net::Cmd, fixed in 3.08.  Upgrade Net::Cmd to 3.08 or later, or correct the offending line (around line 530 and 573) by changing:

```
  unless (defined($w) && $w == $len) {
```

to

```
  unless (defined($w) && $w > 0) {
```

That line causes the connection to fail immediately if it needs to send more than one chunk, even though the code already properly handles sending more than one chunk.  Hence when you have to send a large amount, it fails, if not (without the attachment) it succeeds.

Comment: Thanks for that insight, I'll have to verify this is the case before I accept your answer but it sounds spot on.

Comment: It was for me on Ubuntu 16.04 which has 3.05.

Comment: That's strange because I also have Ubuntu 16.04 but the patch didn't help me. But upgrading Net::Cmd using CPAN did, so still upvote.

Answer (score 0):

[Net::SMTP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::SMTP) also supports SSL. You might want to try it as a drop-in replacement for Net::SMTP::SSL, but I doubt it would make a big difference.

Try enabling the debug mode to see what's happening:

```
my $mailer = new Net::SMTP::SSL($smtp, Port => $port, Debug => 1) or die "Cannot create a SSL mailer instance!\n";
```

You should try to find out if the problem is related to emails starting from a certain size (1k? 8k?).

Gmail never just closes a connection inbetween, they always return an error message if the connection is closed by intend.

Comment: I will attempt to use the debug mode, as well as use Net::SMTP. Thanks for the alternative I'll get back to you with if that solves things, or answer the question if the debugger sheds any light on it.